# 2.81 How to re-center a pivot to object center?

Tags: objects

TRANSFORM ORIGIN!Blender Today Live #74 youtube.com/watch?v=fCxnrwbsdlw&feature=youtu.be&t=193

After moving the pivot from the center of object 1, how to recenter the pivot to object 1? 
is there a function to do this (like: "object recenter pivot"?)

Comment: You can reset the origin location by setting the origin to geometry (if that's where the origin was before transforming it). Not sure about rotation and scale.